# How can I decompress a gzip stream with zlib?

Tags: gzip, zlib, inflate

Gzip format files (created with the `gzip` program, for example) use the "deflate" compression algorithm, which is the same compression algorithm as what [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) uses. However, when using zlib to inflate a gzip compressed file, the library returns a `Z_DATA_ERROR`.

How can I use zlib to decompress a gzip file?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

To decompress a gzip format file with zlib, call `inflateInit2` with the `windowBits` parameter as `16+MAX_WBITS`, like this:

```
inflateInit2(&stream, 16+MAX_WBITS);
```

If you don't do this, zlib will complain about a bad stream format. By default, zlib creates streams with a zlib header, and on inflate does not recognise the different gzip header unless you tell it so. Although this is documented starting in version 1.2.1 of the `zlib.h` header file, it is not in the [zlib manual](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#inflateInit2). From the header file:

> `windowBits` can also be greater than 15 for optional gzip decoding. Add
>      32 to `windowBits` to enable zlib and gzip decoding with automatic header
>      detection, or add 16 to decode only the gzip format (the zlib format will
>      return a `Z_DATA_ERROR`).  If a gzip stream is being decoded, `strm->adler` is
>      a crc32 instead of an adler32.

Comment: In python: `zlib.decompress(data, 15 + 32)`

Comment: Thanks, this was highly frustrating until I found this post.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide some guidelines for iterative decompression of gzip stream. In one-shot gzip decompression where your output stream and size should be fixed and sufficient for storing the whole decompressed output. This value depends on gzip decompression effectiveness that can vary according to data entropy. Is there a way to dynamically allocate more space to output buffer when needed ? Thanks

Comment: I have no idea how this would work. BUT it does work.

Answer (score 126):

## python

[`zlib` library supports](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html):

- [RFC 1950](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt) (`zlib` compressed format)
- [RFC 1951](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt) (`deflate` compressed format)
- [RFC 1952](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1952.txt) (`gzip` compressed format)

The python `zlib` module will support these as well.

## choosing windowBits

But `zlib` can decompress all those formats:

- to (de-)compress `deflate` format, use `wbits = -zlib.MAX_WBITS`
- to (de-)compress `zlib` format, use `wbits = zlib.MAX_WBITS`
- to (de-)compress `gzip` format, use `wbits = zlib.MAX_WBITS | 16`

See documentation in http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Advanced (section `inflateInit2`)

## examples

test data:

```
>>> deflate_compress = zlib.compressobj(9, zlib.DEFLATED, -zlib.MAX_WBITS)
>>> zlib_compress = zlib.compressobj(9, zlib.DEFLATED, zlib.MAX_WBITS)
>>> gzip_compress = zlib.compressobj(9, zlib.DEFLATED, zlib.MAX_WBITS | 16)
>>> 
>>> text = '''test'''
>>> deflate_data = deflate_compress.compress(text) + deflate_compress.flush()
>>> zlib_data = zlib_compress.compress(text) + zlib_compress.flush()
>>> gzip_data = gzip_compress.compress(text) + gzip_compress.flush()
>>>
```

obvious test for `zlib`:

```
>>> zlib.decompress(zlib_data)
'test'
```

test for `deflate`:

```
>>> zlib.decompress(deflate_data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
>>> zlib.decompress(deflate_data, -zlib.MAX_WBITS)
'test'
```

test for `gzip`:

```
>>> zlib.decompress(gzip_data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
>>> zlib.decompress(gzip_data, zlib.MAX_WBITS|16)
'test'
```

the data is also compatible with `gzip` module:

```
>>> import gzip
>>> import StringIO
>>> fio = StringIO.StringIO(gzip_data)
>>> f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=fio)
>>> f.read()
'test'
>>> f.close()
```

### automatic header detection (zlib or gzip)

adding `32` to `windowBits` will trigger header detection

```
>>> zlib.decompress(gzip_data, zlib.MAX_WBITS|32)
'test'
>>> zlib.decompress(zlib_data, zlib.MAX_WBITS|32)
'test'
```

### using `gzip` instead

For `gzip` data with gzip header you can use `gzip` module directly; but [please remember that under the hood](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/gzip.py), `gzip` uses `zlib`.

```
fh = gzip.open('abc.gz', 'rb')
cdata = fh.read()
fh.close()
```

Comment: why this piece of gold is not on the docs on this exactly format?

Comment: please feel free to send a pull request / patch against cpython using any of this answer.

Comment: great answer for strings, any idea how to do this for a stream without reading the entire file into memory?

Comment: Thank you. I can solve my decompress problem in my source code with your answer.

Comment: incredible, this is a gold nugget.. however i can't help but feel these are tantamount to 'magic numbers'? where in the documentation is this mentioned? i looked, but must have really not checked hard enough.. also, the notation i don't fully follow. What does the | mean, is that optional? and why is deflate negative.. is MAX_WBITS a constant.. 

Comment: @m1nkeh: In Python, as in most (if not all) languages, `|` is the bitwise-`OR` operator, like `+`, `-`, `*` and so on. In practice, it is used to "set the bits" in a number. So `zlib.MAX_WBITS | 16` means: In the number `zlib.MAX_WBITS`, "turn on" the bits that are set in 16 (which, being a power of 2, is a single bit).

Answer (score 6):

The structure of zlib and gzip is different. zlib  uses [RFC 1950](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt) and gzip uses [RFC 1952](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1952.txt),
so have different headers but the rest have the same structure and follows the [RFC 1951](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt).