# In gzip library, what's the difference between 'uncompress' and 'gzopen'?

Tags: zlib

There are some functions to decompress in zlib library (zlib version 1.2.3)

I want to decompress my source zip (.gz) file using `uncompress` function.
It is not working (error code -3) but gzopen is. It is still not working when I input payload pointer (passing gzip header) to `uncompress`.

So the question is:

- What's the valid arguments for uncompress function?
- If it needs different format, how can I make it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use some poorly documented features of the zlib library. See my answer to this question for more information: [How can I decompress a gzip stream with zlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838699/how-can-i-decompress-a-gzip-stream-with-zlib)