# Python decompressing gzip chunk-by-chunk

Tags: python, gzip, zlib

I've a memory- and disk-limited environment where I need to decompress the contents of a gzip file sent to me in string-based chunks (over xmlrpc binary transfer). However, using the zlib.decompress() or zlib.decompressobj()/decompress() both barf over the gzip header. I've tried offsetting past the gzip header (documented [here](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html)), but still haven't managed to avoid the barf. The gzip library itself only seems to support decompressing from files.

The following snippet gives a simplified illustration of what I would like to do (except in real life the buffer will be filled from xmlrpc, rather than reading from a local file):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import zlib

CHUNKSIZE=1000

d = zlib.decompressobj()

f=open('23046-8.txt.gz','rb')
buffer=f.read(CHUNKSIZE)

while buffer:
  outstr = d.decompress(buffer)
  print(outstr)
  buffer=f.read(CHUNKSIZE)

outstr = d.flush()
print(outstr)

f.close()
```

Unfortunately, as I said, this barfs with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 13, in <module>
    outstr = d.decompress(buffer)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing: incorrect header check
```

Theoretically, I could feed my xmlrpc-sourced data into a StringIO and then use that as a fileobj for gzip.GzipFile(), however, in real life, I don't have memory available to hold the entire file contents in memory as well as the decompressed data. I really do need to process it chunk-by-chunk.

The fall-back would be to change the compression of my xmlrpc-sourced data from gzip to plain zlib, but since that impacts other sub-systems I'd prefer to avoid it if possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

gzip and zlib use slightly different headers.

See [How can I decompress a gzip stream with zlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838699/how-can-i-decompress-a-gzip-stream-with-zlib)

Try `d = zlib.decompressobj(16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)`.

And you might try changing your chunk size to a power of 2 (say `CHUNKSIZE=1024`) for possible performance reasons.

Comment: That did it perfectly. Thanks.

(Now, why isn't this hint in the python docs?)

Comment: zlib is just a wrapper around the c version of zlib. It's not well documented at all. Mind you, the 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS isn't documented the c version either, and it's not the first time I've seen an undocumented zlib feature.

Comment: definately needs to be documented!

Comment: This worked fine for my until yesterday. I have a gziped file here that decompresses fine with command-line gzip, decompresses fine with the gzip module in python, but stops prematurely with zlib. As noted elsewhere, gzip wants a real file (that it can seek() on), so I'm now in the market for an alternative gzip and/or zlib implementation.

Comment: Thank you! This should be noted in some official docs. I fought with this for hours...

Answer (score 4):

I've got a more detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22310760/1733117

```
d = zlib.decompressobj(zlib.MAX_WBITS|32)
```

[per documentation this automatically detects the header (zlib or gzip)](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Advanced).

Comment: I don't want to downvote you, but this simply doesn't work for me.

Comment: @gwg try to be more precise, e.g., what specifically does not work for you. Otherwise, people won't be able to help you. Thanks for your kind understanding.

Comment: I wasn't looking for help as the accepted answer worked for me. I was registering this opinion to save others time.