# zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing: incorrect header check

Tags: python, gzip, zlib

I have a gzip file and I am trying to read it via Python as below:

```
import zlib

do = zlib.decompressobj(16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)
fh = open('abc.gz', 'rb')
cdata = fh.read()
fh.close()
data = do.decompress(cdata)
```

it throws this error:

```
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing: incorrect header check
```

How can I overcome it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: [dnozay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22310760/172599) explains the problem and should be the accepted answer.

---

Try the `gzip` module, code below is straight from the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html?highlight=gzip#module-gzip).

```
import gzip
f = gzip.open('/home/joe/file.txt.gz', 'rb')
file_content = f.read()
f.close()
```

Comment: Same error presented :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/gzip.py", line 212, in read
    self._read(readsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/gzip.py", line 271, in _read
    uncompress = self.decompress.decompress(buf)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing: invalid code lengths set

Comment: @VarunVyas, sorry, I can't reproduce your error. It must have something to do with your input data. Was your input file generated with gzip? Does gunzip from the command line decompress it correctly?

Answer (score 160):

You have this error:

```
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing: incorrect header check
```

Which is most likely because you are trying to check headers that are not there, e.g. your data follows `RFC 1951` (`deflate` compressed format) rather than `RFC 1950` (`zlib` compressed format) or `RFC 1952` (`gzip` compressed format).

## choosing windowBits

But `zlib` can decompress all those formats:

- to (de-)compress `deflate` format, use `wbits = -zlib.MAX_WBITS`
- to (de-)compress `zlib` format, use `wbits = zlib.MAX_WBITS`
- to (de-)compress `gzip` format, use `wbits = zlib.MAX_WBITS | 16`

See documentation in http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Advanced (section `inflateInit2`)

## examples

test data:

```
>>> deflate_compress = zlib.compressobj(9, zlib.DEFLATED, -zlib.MAX_WBITS)
>>> zlib_compress = zlib.compressobj(9, zlib.DEFLATED, zlib.MAX_WBITS)
>>> gzip_compress = zlib.compressobj(9, zlib.DEFLATED, zlib.MAX_WBITS | 16)
>>> 
>>> text = '''test'''
>>> deflate_data = deflate_compress.compress(text) + deflate_compress.flush()
>>> zlib_data = zlib_compress.compress(text) + zlib_compress.flush()
>>> gzip_data = gzip_compress.compress(text) + gzip_compress.flush()
>>>
```

obvious test for `zlib`:

```
>>> zlib.decompress(zlib_data)
'test'
```

test for `deflate`:

```
>>> zlib.decompress(deflate_data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
>>> zlib.decompress(deflate_data, -zlib.MAX_WBITS)
'test'
```

test for `gzip`:

```
>>> zlib.decompress(gzip_data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
>>> zlib.decompress(gzip_data, zlib.MAX_WBITS|16)
'test'
```

the data is also compatible with `gzip` module:

```
>>> import gzip
>>> import StringIO
>>> fio = StringIO.StringIO(gzip_data)  # io.BytesIO for Python 3
>>> f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=fio)
>>> f.read()
'test'
>>> f.close()
```

## automatic header detection (zlib or gzip)

adding `32` to `windowBits` will trigger header detection

```
>>> zlib.decompress(gzip_data, zlib.MAX_WBITS|32)
'test'
>>> zlib.decompress(zlib_data, zlib.MAX_WBITS|32)
'test'
```

## using `gzip` instead

or you can ignore `zlib` and use `gzip` module directly; but [please remember that under the hood](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/gzip.py), `gzip` uses `zlib`.

```
fh = gzip.open('abc.gz', 'rb')
cdata = fh.read()
fh.close()
```

Comment: this: `zlib.decompress(gzip_data, zlib.MAX_WBITS|32)`

Comment: @dnozay, I've tried using the above `zlib.decompress(zlib_data, zlib.MAX_WBITS|32)` tweak that you mentioned, but it hasn't worked. I still get the `incorrect header check` error. If I try using the the other options mentioned above, I still get various errors. Is there anything else that could trigger this error?

Comment: @Minu, sure -- any kind of data that's neither valid deflate, zlib or gzip content would fail the header check.

Comment: `zlib.MAX_WBITS | 16` worked for me, thanks. It is amazingly non-trivial to deduce this from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/zlib.html#zlib.decompress). Also, it's annoying that `aiohttp` doesn't decode `Content-Encoding: gzip` transparently.

Answer (score 3):

I just solved the "incorrect header check" problem when uncompressing gzipped data.

You need to set -WindowBits => WANT_GZIP in your call to inflateInit2 (use the 2 version)

Yes, this can be very frustrating. A typically shallow reading of the documentation presents Zlib as an API to Gzip compression, but by default (not using the gz* methods) it does not create or uncompress the Gzip format. You have to send this non-very-prominently documented flag.

Answer (score 3):

This does not answer the original question, but it may help someone else that ends up here.

The `zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing: incorrect header check` also occurs in the example below:

```
b64_encoded_bytes = base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(b'abcde'))
encoded_bytes_representation = str(b64_encoded_bytes)  # this the cause
zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(encoded_bytes_representation))
```

The example is a minimal reproduction of something I encountered in some legacy Django code, where [Base64](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) encoded bytes (from an HTTP POST) were being stored in a Django [`CharField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#charfield) (instead of a [`BinaryField`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4915397)).

When reading a `CharField` value from the database, `str()` is called on the value, *without* an explicit `encoding`, as can be seen in the [Django source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1027).

The `str()` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) says:

> If neither encoding nor errors is given, str(object) returns object.**str**(), which is the “informal” or nicely printable string representation of object. For string objects, this is the string itself. If object does not have a **str**() method, then str() falls back to returning repr(object).

So, in the example, we are inadvertently base64-decoding

`"b'eJxLTEpOSQUABcgB8A=='"`

instead of

`b'eJxLTEpOSQUABcgB8A=='`.

The `zlib` decompression in the example would succeed if an explicit `encoding` were used, e.g. `str(b64_encoded_bytes, 'utf-8')`.

NOTE specific to Django:

What's especially tricky: this issue only arises when *retrieving* a value from the database. See for example the test below, which *passes* (in Django 3.0.3):

```
class MyModelTests(TestCase):
    def test_bytes(self):
        my_model = MyModel.objects.create(data=b'abcde')
        self.assertIsInstance(my_model.data, bytes)  # issue does not arise
        my_model.refresh_from_db()
        self.assertIsInstance(my_model.data, str)  # issue does arise
```

where `MyModel` is

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    data = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Answer (score 2):

To decompress incomplete gzipped bytes that are in memory, the [answer by dnozay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22310760/) is useful but it misses the `zlib.decompressobj` call which I found to be necessary:

```
incomplete_decompressed_content = zlib.decompressobj(wbits=zlib.MAX_WBITS | 16).decompress(incomplete_gzipped_content)
```

Note that `zlib.MAX_WBITS | 16` is `15 | 16` which is 31. For some background about `wbits`, see [`zlib.decompress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.decompress).

---

Credit: [answer by Yann Vernier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19117578/) which notes the the `zlib.decompressobj` call.

Answer (score 1):

Funnily enough, I had that error when trying to work with the Stack Overflow API using Python.

I managed to get it working with the `GzipFile` object from the gzip directory, roughly like this:

```
import gzip

gzip_file = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=open('abc.gz', 'rb'))

file_contents = gzip_file.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

My case was to decompress email messages that are stored in Bullhorn database. The snippet is the following:

```
import pyodbc
import zlib

cn = pyodbc.connect('connection string')
cursor = cn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT TOP(1) userMessageID, commentsCompressed FROM BULLHORN1.BH_UserMessage WHERE DATALENGTH(commentsCompressed) > 0 ')



 for msg in cursor.fetchall():
    #magic in the second parameter, use negative value for deflate format
    decompressedMessageBody = zlib.decompress(bytes(msg.commentsCompressed), -zlib.MAX_WBITS)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Node.js` , try `fflate` package, that worked for me for `gzip`.

```
const fflate = require('fflate');
```

```js
    const decompressedData = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           fflate.gunzip(buffer, (error, result) => {
                       if (error) {
                       reject(error);
                       } else {
                       resolve(result);
                      }
                   });
                });
           xml = Buffer.from(decompressedData).toString('UTF-8');
```

Answer (score -3):

Just add headers 'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'

```
import requests

requests.get('http://gett.bike/', headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'})
```

https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/3849

Comment: So your answer to a decompression question is: don't compress it to start with??

Comment: Servers don't always respect the stated header, so this doesn't reliably work.