# Django Blob Model Field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, django-blob

How do you store a "blob" of binary data using Django's ORM, with a PostgreSQL backend? Yes, I know Django frowns upon that sort of thing, and yes, I know they prefer you use the ImageField or FileField for that, but suffice it to say, that's impractical for my application.

I've tried hacking it by using a TextField, but I get occassional errors when my binary data doesn't strictly confirm to the models encoding type, which is unicode by default. e.g.

```
psycopg2.DataError: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe22665
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This snippet any good:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1597/

> This is possibly the simplest solution for storing binary data in a
>   TextField.

```
import base64

from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):

    _data = models.TextField(
            db_column='data',
            blank=True)

    def set_data(self, data):
        self._data = base64.encodestring(data)

    def get_data(self):
        return base64.decodestring(self._data)

    data = property(get_data, set_data)
```

There's a couple of other snippets there that might help.

Comment: Thanks. I had been using something similar, but that snippet's far more simple.

Comment: Thanks for the great snippet. Do you know if this supports filtering? i.e. Does `Foo.objects.filter(data=my_file)` process `my_file` through `get_data`?

Answer (score 38):

If you're using Django >= 1.6, there's a [BinaryField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield)

Answer (score 10):

I have been using this simple field for 'mysql' backend, you can modify it for other backends

```
class BlobField(models.Field):
    description = "Blob"
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'blob'
```

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail, I was investigating at that point. As of Django 1.2 the [db_type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_type) method takes a `connection` argument. This was the cause of the exception during `syncdb`. I have amended the code.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check out [Django Storages' Database Storage:](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/database.html).

I haven't used it yet, but it looks awesome and I'm going to start using it as soon as I Post My Answer.