# Django storing non-unicode data

Tags: python, django, postgresql, unicode, utf-8

I'm attempting to store IP packet payloads in a PostgreSQL database with Django.

Currently, I'm storying the payload as a CharField.

I'm getting this error:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xedbc93
HINT:  This error can also happen if the byte sequence does not match the encoding expected by the server, which is controlled by "client_encoding".
```

Is there any way to sanely store this data? I'm able to do `str(packet.payload)` with no errors, but when Django tries to save the object it throws the encoding error. A bytestring seems like the obvious solution, but it doesn't look like Django supports that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to store arbitrary bytestrings, you should declare them as such.  Many (most?) sequences of bytes are not valid UTF-8, so it isn't a good way to store them.  A CharField is for storing text, and you don't have text.

The answers to this question will likely be helpful: [Django Blob Model Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915397/django-blob-model-field)

Comment: What he said. An IP packet payload is a binary blob. It's neither a string nor is it Unicode. Even if the protocol is 100% Unicode text, it is possible for a packet payload to be invalid Unicode.