# How to download data in a blob field from database in django?

Tags: django, blob

I have a table in which I have a blob column containing some data, how can i download the blob content in django?
I tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915397/django-blob-model-field) but it didn't work for me

Comment: What format do you want it in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def download_blob(request, id):

    contents = BlobModel.objects.get(id=id).blob_field

    response = HttpResponse(contents)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=blob.bin'
    return response
```

Comment: Works like a charme ! THANK YOU! been searching for 2 days !