# Django file saving to sqlite3 db and retrieval

Tags: django, django-admin, django-file-upload

The following is my device model:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    device_type         = models.ForeignKey(DeviceType,to_field='device_type')
    serial_number       = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    in_use_by           = models.ForeignKey(User,to_field='username')
    brand               = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="-", null=False)
    model               = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="-", null=False)
    type_number         = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True, default = None)
    mac_address         = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True, default = None)
    invoice             = models.FileField(upload_to='', null=True)
```

Here, the invoice field is not of use to me in my website but, it is of use to me as a admin. What I am basically trying to do is, if a device request is accepted then, I will upload the invoice of the device into my sqlite db using the admin panel. I am a newbie to Django and hence, require help for this purpose. 
Also, I will only upload file through django admin. How should I achieve this?
What should I write in upload to parameter so that the file is stored in database?

Comment: You don't need to do anything. Once you enable your model in the admin as shown in the tutorial, you will be able to upload your files.

Comment: And for downloading is there any special functionality needed?

Comment: You don't store the file itself in the database. Store the file on disk and the path to it in the database. Then downloading is just constructing a link from the path.

Comment: But, if I want to store in database then, how can it be achieved?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It is inefficient and unnecessary, especially with an sqlite db which is just a file on the filesystem anyway.

Comment: I just want to have knowledge regarding that stuff. hence, I was asking about that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your Admin with the required fields you want to edit.

In **admin.py**:

```
class DeviceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('device_type', 'invoice', ..)

admin.site.register(Device, DeviceAdmin)
```

[Django Admin field reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields)

**EDIT**:

`upload_to` parameter is the path where you need to store the file. Generally it is the `MEDIA_ROOT` path as configured in Django settings.

```
models.FileField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT, null=True)
```

To serve this during development:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

[Refer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-uploaded-files-in-development)

In the DB, only the URL of the file will be stored.

Comment: But what should be passed in upload_to parameter in FileField so that my file ges stored in sqlite3 db?

Comment: `upload_to` parameter is for the directory you want to save the file in. And the path should come from settings.py file. When you retrieve this field it will give you URL of the file.

Comment: Ok, there must be some way to store files in DB right?

Comment: Edited the answer for `FileField`. Django's `FileField` only stores link. If you need to store the file in the DB you need to look at storing blob in DB. For which you need to create a Custom Field dependent on your DB. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915397/django-blob-model-field