# Python zlib gzip decompression fails with string compressed on client side via pako

Tags: javascript, python, compression, gzip, zlib

I want to decompress a JSON object on server (with Python's zlib) side that I gzipped on in the browser with the JS library [pako](https://nodeca.github.io/pako/#gzip). The compressed string is sent to the server via XHR.
Unfortunately the server-side Python application fails with

> Error -3 while decompressing: incorrect header check

The code I use for client-side compression:

```js
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
var zlibOpts = {
    level: 9,
    to: 'string'
};
data = pako.gzip(json, zlibOpts);
```

The server-side code:

```
zlib_window_size = 31
result = zlib.decompressobj().decompress(data, zlib_window_size)
```

I figured out that the `windowBits` is important for zlib to recognize the string as being gzip-compressed (as stated [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122145/zlib-error-error-3-while-decompressing-incorrect-header-check#22310760) and the [zlib docs](http://zlib.net/manual.html#Advanced)) so I used the same which paco uses for compression (`31`).

I also tried without any `windowBits` and with `zlib.MAX_WBITS|16` or `zlib.MAX_WBITS|32` in Python, wich fails with the same error.

The server side application is running on Tornado.

Any help/hint is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `zlib_window_size` from `decompress()` to `decompressobj()`. Or just get rid of the `decompressobj()`. You don't need it for a single call of `decompress()`.

Comment: Thanks. Providing `31` as `window_size` parameter to `decompressobj()` somehow did the trick.