# Decompress Python requests response with zlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, zlib, compression

I'm trying to decompress the response from a web request using Python requests and zlib but I'm not able to decompress the response content properly.  Here's my code:

```
import requests
import zlib

URL = "http://" #omitted real url
r = requests.get(URL)
print r.content
data = zlib.decompress(r.content, lib.MAX_WBITS)
print data
```

However, I keep getting various errors when changing the wbits parameter.

```
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid stored block lengths
```

I tried the wbits parameters for deflate, zlip and gzip as noted here [zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing: incorrect header check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122145/zlib-error-error-3-while-decompressing-incorrect-header-check/22310760)

But still can't get pass these errors.  I'm trying to this in Python, I was given this piece of code that did it with Objective-C but I don't know Objective-C

```
#import "GTMNSData+zlib.h"
+ (NSData*) uncompress: (NSData*) data
{
    Byte *bytes= (Byte*)[data bytes];
    NSInteger length=[data length];
    NSMutableData* retdata=[[NSMutableData alloc]   initWithCapacity:length*3.5];

    NSInteger bSize=0;
    NSInteger offSet=0;
    while (true) {
        offSet+=bSize;
        if (offSet>=length) {
            break;
        }
        bSize=bytes[offSet];
        bSize+=(bytes[offSet+1]<<8);
        bSize+=(bytes[offSet+2]<<16);
        bSize+=(bytes[offSet+3]<<24);
        offSet+=4;
        if ((bSize==0)||(bSize+offSet>length)) {
            LogError(@"Invalid");
            return data;
        }
        [retdata appendData:[NSData gtm_dataByInflatingBytes: bytes+offSet length:bSize]];
    }
    return retdata; 
}
```

Comment: The contents are not a single zlib stream but rather a series of them each prefixed with a 4 byte little endian length. I could probably write a decoder.

Comment: I'm having the same trouble, curious to know if you found a solution ...

Answer (score 1):

According to Python requests documentation at:

- http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content

it says:

```
You can also access the response body as bytes, for non-text requests:

>>> r.content
b'[{"repository":{"open_issues":0,"url":"https://github.com/...

The gzip and deflate transfer-encodings are automatically decoded for you.
```

If requests understand the encoding, it should therefore already be uncompressed.

Use `r.raw` if you need to get access to the original data to handle a different decompression mechanism.

- http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content

Answer (score 0):

The following is an untested translation of the Objective-C code:

```
import zlib
import struct

def uncompress(data):
    length = len(data)
    ret = []
    bSize = 0
    offSet = 0
    while True:
        offSet += bSize
        if offSet >= length:
            break

        bSize = struct.unpack("<i", data[offSet:offSet+4])
        offSet += 4
        if bSize == 0 or bSize + offSet > length:
           print "Invalid"
           return ''.join(ret)
        ret.append(zlib.decompress(data[offSet:offSet+bSize]))

   return ''.join(ret)
```