# zlib python error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check

Tags: python, python-2.7

The essence of the question is, has mysql database it is compressed using zlib data.
When unpacking the machine where they are compressed all ok.
On another machine

```
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

compressed:

```
fmt = '%df' % (num_of_p,)
dist = buffer(zlib.compress( struct.pack(fmt, *data), 9 ))
```

unpacking:

```
dist = struct.unpack ( '% df'% (num_of_p - 1,), zlib.decompress (data))
```

On the machine where the packed python 2.7.3
On the machine where the unpacked python 2.7.13

Comment: duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122145/zlib-error-error-3-while-decompressing-incorrect-header-check

Comment: Possible duplicate of [zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing: incorrect header check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122145/zlib-error-error-3-while-decompressing-incorrect-header-check)