# Getting rid of error generating documents from a corpus

Tags: python, error-handling, zlib

I have a set of 1000 documents - encoded and compressed - in an [lsm-db](http://lsm-db.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) stored on my computer. When I try to decompress and decode, I get an error that says "Incorrect Header Check".

This is what I'm doing:

```
for key in my_lsm_db.keys():
    print key, zlib.decompress(my_lsm_db[key], zlib.MAX_WBITS|32).decode('utf-8')
```

After processing a few keys, the code throws an error. The error that I'm receiving is: `error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check`

**I want to remove all such error generating documents from the corpus. How can I identify the documents that generate the error, so I could remove them?**

```
def remove_docs(my_lsm_db):
    for key in my_lsm_db.keys():
        ## write code that identifies an error when generated
        if <code that identifies document generating error>:
            del my_lsm_db[key]
```

Here's some information on Zlib and `MAX_WBITS` part of the code: [Zlib Compression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html), [Stack Overflow Answer for Zlib Automatic Header Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122145/zlib-error-error-3-while-decompressing-incorrect-header-check/22310760#22310760)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using a try/except block around my code to overcome such error generating documents. It works for not just the above code, but other stuff also.

```
try:
    <code to execute>
except (<list of errors>) as e:
    print e
```