# How to open a remote .FTS.gz file with astropy.io.fits.open()?

Tags: gzip, astropy, fits

**Summary of a problem:**

I am writing some code that checks the content of a FTS file header (data saved from a telescope) using astropy.io.fits. My problem is when I try to open .FTS.gz files instead of .FTS files on a remote server. When I `open()` a .FTS.gz I get errors, if I `gunzip` the .FTS.gz file, all is good. One of the errors suggest I have an END missing card. Searching online, I used a suggestion of using the `ignore_missing_end=True` argument in `fits.open()`, but then I get the next error. This next error suggests my FITS file is empty or corrupt, however it is not the case. I can open it with SAOImage DS9 without any problems, plus I have run [this handy online tool](https://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/fits_verify.html) called `fitsverify` which reports no errors in my file. If I download the offending file .FTS.gz and run a similar code to `fits.open()` this file locally, I get no errors at all. An example of an offending file (used in the code below) is now uploaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lt072j9urm10i6l/RUN0001.FTS.gz?dl=0).

The Astropy documentation says:
"Working with compressed files
The `open()` function will seamlessly open FITS files that have been compressed with gzip, bzip2 or pkzip. Note that in this context we’re talking about a fits file that has been compressed with one of these utilities - e.g. a .fits.gz file."

How do I open a remote .FTS.gz file without downloading it? I have hundreds of thousands of files like this, so downloading is not an option and it is not just one file that gives a problem, it is all of them.

Thanks,
Aina.

**Code and errors:**

CODE TO OPEN A REMOTE .FTS.gz FILE:

```
from astropy.io import fits
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect('myhostname', username='myusername', password='mypassword')
apath = '/path/to/folder/to/search'
apattern = '"RUN0001.FTS.gz"'
rawcommand = 'find {path} -name {pattern}'
command = rawcommand.format(path=apath, pattern=apattern)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
filelist = stdout.read().splitlines()
for i in filelist:
    sftp_client = client.open_sftp()
    remote_file = sftp_client.open(i)
    hdulist = fits.open(remote_file)
client.close()
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amusaeva/Documents/PyCharm/FITSHeaders/stackoverflow.py", line 17, in <module>
    hdulist = fits.open(remote_file)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/hdu/hdulist.py", line 166, in fitsopen
    lazy_load_hdus, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/hdu/hdulist.py", line 404, in fromfile
    lazy_load_hdus=lazy_load_hdus, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/hdu/hdulist.py", line 1040, in _readfrom
    read_one = hdulist._read_next_hdu()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/hdu/hdulist.py", line 1135, in _read_next_hdu
    hdu = _BaseHDU.readfrom(fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/hdu/base.py", line 329, in readfrom
    **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/hdu/base.py", line 394, in _readfrom_internal
    header = Header.fromfile(data, endcard=not ignore_missing_end)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/header.py", line 450, in fromfile
    padding)[1]
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/header.py", line 519, in _from_blocks
    raise IOError('Header missing END card.')
IOError: Header missing END card.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

CHANGING THE CODE ABOVE FOR ONE LINE ONLY:

```
hdulist = fits.open(remote_file, ignore_missing_end=True)
```

ERROR:

```
WARNING: VerifyWarning: Error validating header for HDU #0 (note: Astropy uses zero-based indexing).
    Header size is not multiple of 2880: 7738429
There may be extra bytes after the last HDU or the file is corrupted. [astropy.io.fits.hdu.hdulist]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amusaeva/Documents/PyCharm/FITSHeaders/stackoverflow.py", line 17, in <module>
    hdulist = fits.open(remote_file, ignore_missing_end=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/hdu/hdulist.py", line 166, in fitsopen
    lazy_load_hdus, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/hdu/hdulist.py", line 404, in fromfile
    lazy_load_hdus=lazy_load_hdus, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/hdu/hdulist.py", line 1044, in _readfrom
    raise IOError('Empty or corrupt FITS file')
IOError: Empty or corrupt FITS file

Process finished with exit code 1
```

CODE TO OPEN THE OFFENDING .FTS.gz FILE LOCALLY PRODUCES NO ERRORS:

```
import os
from astropy.io import fits

folderTosearch = "/path/to/folder/to/search/locally";
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folderTosearch):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith("RUN0001.FTS.gz"):
            hdulist = fits.open(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the sftp call passes some variant of a file-like object (which has a `.read()` method that `fits.open()` will use.
The file like object, however, is still a gzip file. Astropy checks whether a file is zipped *only* for file *names*, that is, when the argument to `fits.open()` is a string (that happens to be a path). Astropy does not appear to test for the magic bytes that identify a byte stream as a gzip file. Oddly enough, it does do this verification when path strings are passed. Arguably, this may be a slight shortcoming in the astropy.io.fits module, but perhaps there's a reason for it.
(Disclaimer: the above conclusion is from scanning quickly through [the relevant source code](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/blob/master/astropy/io/fits/file.py); I may have missed something. Hopefully people will correct me if so.)

One solution is to do the unzipping yourself. I've cobbled up the following:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import zlib

<...>

for i in filelist:                                                                       
    sftp_client = client.open_sftp()                                                     
    remote_file = sftp_client.open(i)                                                    
    decompressed = StringIO(                                                             
        zlib.decompress(remote_file.read(), zlib.MAX_WBITS|32))                          
    hdulist = fits.open(decompressed)                                                    
    client.close()
```

Above, we're reading the full contents of the remote file (`remote_file.read()`, then uncompressing the contents. That results in a string, so we wrap it in a `StringIO` instance to make it a file-like object again, that we can pass to `fits.open()`. (For the `zlib.MAX_WBITS|32` argument: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22310760).)

---

Alternatively, you can sftp the file to local disk, and then read the file (with the local filename) locally. The above just keeps everything in memory.

Comment: Everet, `decompressed = StringIO(zlib.decompress(remote_file.read(), zlib.MAX_WBITS|32)) ` totally works! I didn't think the compression was an issue because `hdulist = fits.open(remote_file)` gave me no problem for RUN0001.FTS, only gave me error for RUN0001.FTS.gz! Now I have another problem of my code being insanely slow, but one step at a time, thanks!

Comment: "Oddly enough, it does do this verification when path strings are passed. Arguably, this may be a slight shortcoming in the astropy.io.fits module, but perhaps there's a reason for it.  "

I think that's an oversight. Can you open an issue for it?

Comment: I've opened an issue, as this does seem like a strange oversight: https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/5948