# How to uncompress a message with kdb (32 bit)?

Tags: compression, kdb

I'm trying to decompress a message optimized by Deflate compression in kdb i.e. the following message:

```
0xab562a494cca4955b2522a2e4f2cd0cf4d2cca8e2f28ca4c4e55d2514a492c4954b28aae56cacc2b2e292acd4dcd2b89cf4c012a750a71d60d0d76d10d0e770c00aa43d264a56462606a68ac6709142ec9cc4d2d2e49cc2d00ea30323032d4350022cb1043732b230b2b23333d2323a328a5dad85a00
```

How should one implement this in kdb?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest option here would be to use the zlib Python library via [embedPy](https://github.com/kxsystems/embedPy).

The byte string is passed to the decompress function with the Deflate settings found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122145/zlib-error-error-3-while-decompressing-incorrect-header-check). In Python this returns a bytes object, so we can decode this using UTF-8 into a Python string, with the final backtick (`) specifying that we want this to be returned as a q type (also a string).

We can then convert this from a JSON string into a KDB object using .j.k

```
q)\l p.q
q)zlib:.p.import`zlib
q)i:0xab562a494cca4955b2522a2e4f2cd0cf4d2cca8e2f28ca4c4e55d2514a492c4954b28aae56cacc2b2e292acd4dcd2b89cf4c012a750a71d60d0d76d10d0e770c00aa43d264a56462606a68ac6709142ec9cc4d2d2e49cc2d00ea30323032d4350022cb1043732b230b2b23333d2323a328a5dad85a00
q).j.k zlib[`:decompress][i;neg zlib[`:MAX_WBITS]`][`:decode;"utf-8"]`
table| "swap/mark_price"
data | +`instrument_id`mark_price`timestamp!(,"BTC-USD-SWAP";,"40513.9";,"2021-01-09T17:28:26.222Z")
```