# python + urllib2: streaming ends prematurely

Tags: python, urllib2, zlib

I'm trying to process a large gzip file pulled from the internet in python using urllib2 and zlib and techniques from these two stackoverflow questions:

- [Python decompressing gzip chunk-by-chunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423866/python-decompressing-gzip-chunk-by-chunk)
- [Stream large binary files with urllib2 to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517616/stream-large-binary-files-with-urllib2-to-file)

This works great, except that after each chunk of the file is read, I need to do some operations on the resultant string which involve a lot of splitting and iterating. This takes some time and when the code goes to do the next `req.read()`, it returns nothing, and the program ends, having only read the first chunk.

If I comment out the other operations, the whole file is read and decompressed. Code:

```
d = zlib.decompressobj(16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)
CHUNK = 16 * 1024
url = 'http://foo.bar/foo.gz'
req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
while True:
    chunk = req.read(CHUNK)
    if not chunk:
        print "DONE"
        break
    s = d.decompress(chunk)
    # ...
    # lots of operations with s
    # which might take a while
    # but not more than 1-2 seconds
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
This turned out to be a bug elsewhere in the program, NOT in the urllib2/zlib handling. Thanks to everyone who helped. I can recommend the pattern used in the code above if you need to handle large gzip files.

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you put the long operations on `s` in its own function?

Comment: What happens if you replace the other operations with time.sleep(2)?

Comment: How long is 'some time'.. Seconds? Minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug elsewhere in the program, NOT in the urllib2/zlib handling. I can recommend the pattern used in the code above if you need to handle large gzip files.

Answer (score 1):

If timing out is the issue, and it's not clear that it is, you could decouple the input reading and processing sides of your code by sticking a queue in the middle and doing the processing in another thread that reads from the queue.

You could also make your chunk size smaller and do less processing per loop.