# python tar file how to extract file into stream

Tags: python, stream, tar

I am trying to extract a zipped folder but instead of directly using `.extractall()`, I want to extract the file into stream so that I can handle the stream myself. Is it possible to do it using `tarfile`? Or is there any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean `tarfile` library?

Comment: Yes,sorry for the typo error

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can obtain each file from a tar file as a python `file` object using the `.extractfile()` method. Loop over the `tarfile.TarFile()` instance to list all entries:

```
import tarfile

with tarfile.open(path) as tf:
    for entry in tf:  # list each entry one by one
        fileobj = tf.extractfile(entry)
        # fileobj is now an open file object. Use `.read()` to get the data.
        # alternatively, loop over `fileobj` to read it line by line.
```

Comment: And if the fileobj is a gzip file, would it be possible to decompress it?

Comment: @Werner: the `tarfile` module takes care of compression for you. See the [`tarfile.open()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open), the default mode is `r`, which transparently detects compression and handles decompression as needed.

Comment: Yes, but inside the tarfile I have a gzip file (unfortunately someone created a compressed tarfile with my gzip file…). The `extractfile` returns a `tarfile.ExFileObject` which cannot be used to open a gzip.GzipFile. Would there be a way to open this gzip file without decompressing the tarfile and open the new system file?

Comment: @Werner: I take it you are using Python 2 then? Python 3's `gzip` module should take that object without issues, but the Python 2 version still tries to seek on the file object. Either upgrade to Python 3, or copy the file to disk first, or decode the stream as you read it, see [Python decompressing gzip chunk-by-chunk](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2423866)

Comment: Yes, still on python 2, unfortunately, and it's not possible to upgrade as it makes part of the environment. Ok, thanks a lot! Couldn't find any information on this…

Comment: Evidently you need to be careful with directories; you'll get an entry for them, but when you call `extractfile()` on them, `None` will be returned.

Comment: @MartijnPieters A side question (not sure if it's worth putting as a standalone question), what needs to be done for cleanup of a file object obtained from the `extractfile` method? Is the file extracted on disk anywhere and does that need explicit deletion? (python3)

Comment: @0xc0de: `extractfile` reads directly from the `TarFile` stream, no temp files are created on disk, no cleanup is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to `extractfile` while network streaming a tar file, I did something like this instead:

```
from backports.lzma import LZMAFile
import tarfile
some_streamed_tar = LZMAFile(requests.get('http://some.com/some.tar.xz').content)
with tarfile.open(fileobj=some_streamed_tar) as tf:
    tarfileobj.extractall(path="/tmp", members=None)
```

And to read them:

```
for fn in os.listdir("/tmp"):
    with open(os.path.join(t, fn)) as f:
        print(f.read())
```

python 2.7.13

Comment: You can also achieve this directly with streaming, i.e. without any temporary files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34131505/19163