# subprocess.call and tar -zxvf

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess, tar

I am trying to call this command `tar -zxvf file.tar.gz` from a python script and I'm having trouble with it. I've read some relevant q/a's but I still haven't figured out how to do it.

I was thinking to fit my code to the original command:

```
subprocess.check_call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)
```

So far I've made several attempts, as shown below

```
stdin = file.tar.gz
subprocess.check_call(-zxvf, stdin)
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: `subprocess.check_call(shlex.split("tar -zxvf file.tar.gz"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can untar a file using the `tarfile` module

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open("sample.tar.gz")
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
```

Comment: what if instead of `all()` I need to extract something in particular??

Comment: @EnKei, I'm not sure how to do that. you can probably have a look at the `tarfile` moudles documentation online

Comment: @EnKei This might help for extracting a single file. The answer shows looping through the tar contents, you'll need to add code to match the file you want, but you can extract with tar.extractfile("file")
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562037/python-tar-file-how-to-extract-file-into-stream

[tarfile docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#examples)