# Python: tarfile stream

Tags: python, stream, tarfile

I would like to read some files from a tarball and save it to a new tarball.
This is the code I wrote.

```
archive = 'dum/2164/archive.tar'

# Read input data.
input_tar = tarfile.open(archive, 'r|')
tarinfo = input_tar.next()
input_tar.close()

# Write output file.
output_tar = tarfile.open('foo.tar', 'w|')
output_tar.addfile(tarinfo)
output_tar.close()
```

Unfortunately, the output tarball is no good:

```
$ tar tf foo.tar
./1QZP_A--2JED_A--not_reformatted.dat.bz2
tar: Truncated input file (needed 1548288 bytes, only 1545728 available)
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

Any clue how to read and write tarballs on the fly with Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK so this is how I managed to do it.

```
archive = 'dum/2164/archive.tar'

# Read input data.
input_tar = tarfile.open(archive, 'r|')
tarinfo = input_tar.next()
fileobj = input_tar.extractfile(tarinfo)

# Write output file.
output_tar = tarfile.open('foo.tar', 'w|')
output_tar.addfile(tarinfo, fileobj)

input_tar.close()
output_tar.close()
```

Comment: Note that you can still use the `r|` and `w|` modes so that the data is streamer rather than the entire tarfile read to memory/disk.