# Having Trouble Getting requests==2.7.0 to Automatically Decompress gzip

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to read a gzipped XML file that I request via requests.  Everything that I have read indicates that the the uncompressing should happen automatically.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from __future__ import unicode_literals
import requests

if __name__ == '__main__':

    url = 'http://rdf.dmoz.org/rdf/content.rdf.u8.gz'

    headers = {
        'Accept-Encoding': "gzip,x-gzip,deflate,sdch,compress",
        'Accept-Content': 'gzip',
        'HTTP-Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Accept-Language': "en-US,en;q=0.8",
    }

    request_reply = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    print request_reply.headers

    request_reply.encoding = 'utf-8'
    print request_reply.text[:200]
    print request_reply.content[:200]
```

The header in my first line of output looks like this:

```
{'content-length': '260071268', 'accept-ranges': 'bytes', 'keep-alive': 'timeout=5, max=100', 'server': 'Apache', 'connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'date': 'Tue, 08 Sep 2015 16:27:49 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-gzip'}
```

The next two output lines appear to be binary, where I was expecting XML text:

```
�Iɒ(�����~ؗool���u�rʹ�J���io�   a2R1��ߞ|�<����_��������Ҽҿ=�Z����onnz7�{JO���}h�����6��·��>,aҚ>��hZ6�u��x���?y�_�.y�$�Բ
�Iɒ(�����~ؗool���u�rʹ�J���io�   a2R1��ߞ|�<����_��������Ҽҿ=�Z����onnz7�{JO��}h�����6��·��>,aҚ>��hZ6�u��x���
```

I think part of the problem is that `site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py` does not recognize gzip unless the header has `'content-encoding': 'gzip'`

I was able to get the results I wanted by adding 4 lines to a method in `response.py` like so:

```
    def _init_decoder(self):
        """
        Set-up the _decoder attribute if necessar.
        """
        # Note: content-encoding value should be case-insensitive, per RFC 7230
        # Section 3.2
        content_encoding = self.headers.get('content-encoding', '').lower()
        if self._decoder is None and content_encoding in self.CONTENT_DECODERS:
            self._decoder = _get_decoder(content_encoding)

        # My added code below this comment
            return
        content_type = self.headers.get('content-type', '').lower()
        if self._decoder is None and content_type == 'application/x-gzip':
            self._decoder = _get_decoder('gzip')
```

But, is there a better way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You misunderstood. Only [transport-level compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) is taken care of automatically, so compression applied by the HTTP server.

You have compressed *content*. Since this wasn't applied just for the HTTP transport stage, `requests` won't remove it either.

`requests` communicates to the server that it accepts compressed responses by sending `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` with every request sent. The server can then respond by compressing the whole response body and adding a `Content-Encoding` header indicating the compression used.

Your response has no Content-Encoding header, nor would applying compression again make sense here.

*Most of the time* you want to download an already compressed archive like the DMOZ RDF dataset in the compressed form, *anyway*. You requested a compressed archive after all. It is not the job of the `requests` library to decode that.

In Python 3 you can handle decoding as a stream by using the [`gzip` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html) and streaming the response:

```
import gzip
import requests
import shutil

r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        r.raw.decode_content = True  # just in case transport encoding was applied
        gzip_file = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=r.raw)
        shutil.copyfileobj(gzip_file, f)
```

where you could use an RDF parser instead of copying the decompressed data to disk, of course.

Unfortunately the Python 2 implementation of the module requires a seekable file; you can create your own [streaming wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423866/python-decompressing-gzip-chunk-by-chunk), or by adding that `_decoder` attribute to the `r.raw` object above.