# Unzip buffer with Python?

Tags: python, zip, zlib, unzip, python-zipfile

I have a buffer of bytes read from a library call and I would like to unzip the content which is a single text file.

I tried with `zlib`, but I get this error:

```
>>> import zlib
>>> zlib.decompress(buffer)
error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

However with `ZipFile` it works, but I have to use a temporary file:

```
import zipfile
f = open('foo.zip', 'wb')
f.write(buffer)
f.close()
z = ZipFile('foo.zip')
z.extractall()
z.close()
with open('foo.txt', 'r') as f:
    uncompressed_buffer = f.read()
```

Is it possible to use `zlib` and how can I avoid using a temporary file?

Comment: Have you tried a BytesIO object instead of writing to disc

Comment: `from zlib import decompress, MAX_WBITS; decompress(gz_bytes, 16 + MAX_WBITS)` will do it. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423866/python-decompressing-gzip-chunk-by-chunk).

Comment: @bbayles Same issue with this `incorrect header check`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It doesn't help because I have to give a `filename` to `ZipFile` not a file pointer

Comment: There's a difference between `zlib`'s gzip compression and `zipfile`'s PKZIP compression. I guess yours is the latter?

Comment: Yes it seems I do use PKZIP.

Comment: @nowox,  as per your accepted answer, you can pass a BytesIO to ZipFile which is what I meant

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> Is it possible to use zlib

No, zlib is not designed to operate on ZIP files.

> and how can I avoid using a temporary file?

Use `io.BytesIO`:

```
import zipfile
import io

buffer = b'PK\x03\x04\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\\\x88Gzzo\xed\x03\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x1c\x00foo.txtUT\t\x00\x03$\x14gV(\x14gVux\x0b\x00\x01\x041\x04\x00\x00\x041\x04\x00\x00hi\nPK\x01\x02\x1e\x03\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\\\x88Gzzo\xed\x03\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb4\x81\x00\x00\x00\x00foo.txtUT\x05\x00\x03$\x14gVux\x0b\x00\x01\x041\x04\x00\x00\x041\x04\x00\x00PK\x05\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00M\x00\x00\x00D\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(buffer))

# The following three lines are alternatives. Use one of them
# according to your need:
foo = z.read('foo.txt')        # Reads the data from "foo.txt"
foo2 = z.read(z.infolist()[0]) # Reads the data from the first file
z.extractall()                 # Copies foo.txt to the filesystem

z.close()


print foo
print foo2
```

Comment: This extracts all of the files from the ZIP into the filesystem. If you want to read the data from the compressed file(s), use `z.open()` and `z.read()`.

Comment: @Jarad - Thanks.

Comment: Can you do this as well on a chunk of the 'buffer'; so to say on a stream of data?