# How to read gz compressed files from tar

Tags: python, gzip, tarfile

Let's say we have a tar file which in turn contains multiple gzip compressed files. I want to be able to read the contents of those gzip files without compressing either the tar file or the individual gzip files. I 'm trying to use [tarfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#module-tarfile) module in python.

Answer (score 1):

This might work, I haven't tested it, but this has the main ideas, and related tools. It iterates over the files in the tar, and if they are gzipped, then will read them into the file_contents variable:

```
import tarfile as t
import gzip as g 
for member in t.open("your.gz.tar").getmembers():
    fo=t.extractfile(member)
    file_contents = g.GzipFile(fileobj=fo).read()
```

note: if the file is too large for memory, then consider looking into a streamed reader (chunk by chunk) as linked.

If you have additional logic based on what the member (TarInfo) object looks like you can use these:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tarinfo-objects

see:

- [How can I decompress a gzip stream with zlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838699/how-can-i-decompress-a-gzip-stream-with-zlib)
- [Python decompressing gzip chunk-by-chunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423866/python-decompressing-gzip-chunk-by-chunk)
- [reading tar file contents without untarring it, in python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018512/reading-tar-file-contents-without-untarring-it-in-python-script)