# Gzip In-Memory Compression

Tags: c++, windows, memory, compression, gzip

Quick and simple question.

There are examples online about achieving in-memory gzip compression with zlib (C++) WITHOUT external libraries (like boost or such)?

I just need to compress and decompress a block of data without much options. (it must be gzip as its the same format used by another mine C# program (the data is to be shared))

Tried to search to no avail...
Thanks!

Comment: I assume that zlib is allowed as an external library? :-P

Comment: i want to understand gzip, if i needed a quick fix for my program I would just toss boost inside. :D

Comment: well, zlib is obviously allowed :D

Comment: So - ZLib is a way to go. It's an awesome library. Doesn't depend on any other library.

Comment: Did you look on the zlib site: http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html

Comment: i need in-memory decompression. there's talking only about files there. :P

Comment: and yes, i would need something to explain me what is doing and why. In that page doesn't distinguish between zlib compression and gzip... (that are quite different)

Comment: @feal87 - the calling code is doing file I/O, so from the point of view of zlib, it's all in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer to your question, but you will probably be interested in [How can I decompress a gzip stream with zlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838699/how-can-i-decompress-a-gzip-stream-with-zlib). There is a little bit of poorly documented magic that you need to supply in order for zlib to work with gzip streams.

The zlib API has many functions for doing in-memory compression that don't depend on actual files on disk.

Answer (score 3):

You use an external library called [zlib](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zlib.htm).  You could statically link against this library if you did not want to bundle the DLL with your program.

zlib works happily with in-memory buffers.

You do not require boost.