# Decompress remote .gz file in Python

Tags: python, gzip

i've a issue with Python.

My case: i've a gzipped file from a partner platform (i.e. h..p//....namesite.../xxx)
If i click the link from my browser, it will download a file like (i.e. namefile.xml.gz).

So... if i read this file with python i can decompress and read it.

Code:

```
content = gzip.open(namefile.xml.gz,'rb')
print content.read()
```

But i can't if i try to read the file from remote source.
From remote file i can read only the encoded string, but not decoded it.

Code:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
encoded =response.read()
print encoded
```

With this code i can read the string encoded... but i can't decoded it with gzip or lzip.

Any advices?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the method @Aya suggests does not work, since GzipFile extensively uses `seek` method of the file object (not supported by response).

So you have basically two options:

1. Read the contents of the remote file into `io.StringIO`, and pass the object into `gzip.GzipFile` (if the file is small)
2. download the file into a temporary file on disk, and use `gzip.open`

There is another option (which requires some coding) - to implement your own reader using `zlib` module. It is rather easy, but you will need to know about a magic constant ([How can I decompress a gzip stream with zlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838699/how-can-i-decompress-a-gzip-stream-with-zlib)).

Comment: Thanks, my files is very large and i think that the "temporary folder" is the best method.

Answer (score 0):

For Python v3.2 or later, you can use the [`gzip.GzipFile`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile) class to wrap the file object returned by `urllib2.urlopen()`, with something like this...

```
import urllib2
import gzip

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
gunzip_response = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=response)
content = gunzip_response.read()
print content
```

...which will transparently decompress the response stream as you read it.

Comment: As @newtover mentions, this method won't work with Python <3.2 (including all 2.x versions).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Python 3.2 or later the bug in GzipFile (requiring `tell` support) is fixed, but they apparently aren't going to backport the fix to Python 2.x