# Decompress with gz* functions succeeded but failed with inflate* functions using zlib

Tags: gzip, zlib, compression, inflate

I have a gzip file sample, with standard gzip header `1F 8B 08 00 ...`, when I inflate it with `inflate*` functions in zlib, the output is only 11 bytes(in fact the output should be about 4KB), but when I decompress it with `gz*` functions, it produce the correct output, the code:

1. using `gz*` (this can produce correct output):

   ```
   #define CHUNK 10240
   int gz_decompress(const char *path) {
       gzFile f = gzopen(path, "rb");
       if(!f)
           return -1;

       unsigned char result[CHUNK];
       int bytes_read = gzread(f, result, CHUNK);
       if(bytes_read < CHUNK)
           if(!gzeof(f))
               return -2;
       gzclose (f);
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. using `inflate*` (output is only 11 bytes):

   ```
   #define CHUNK 10240
   int inf(FILE *source)
   {
       int ret;
       unsigned have;
       z_stream strm;
       unsigned char in[CHUNK];
       unsigned char out[CHUNK];

       /* allocate inflate state */
       strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
       strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
       strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
       strm.avail_in = 0;
       strm.next_in = Z_NULL;
       // ret = inflateInit(&strm);
       ret = inflateInit2(&strm, 16 + 15);
       if (ret != Z_OK)
           return ret;

       /* decompress until deflate stream ends or end of file */
       do {
           strm.avail_in = fread(in, 1, CHUNK, source);
           if (strm.avail_in == 0)
               break;
           strm.next_in = in;

           /* run inflate() on input until output buffer not full */
           do {
               strm.avail_out = CHUNK;
               strm.next_out = out;
               ret = inflate(&strm, Z_NO_FLUSH);
               assert(ret != Z_STREAM_ERROR);  /* state not clobbered */
               switch (ret) {
               case Z_NEED_DICT:
                   ret = Z_DATA_ERROR;     /* and fall through */
               case Z_DATA_ERROR:
               case Z_MEM_ERROR:
                   (void)inflateEnd(&strm);
                   return ret;
               }
               have = CHUNK - strm.avail_out;
           } while (strm.avail_out == 0);

           /* done when inflate() says it's done */
       } while (ret != Z_STREAM_END);

       /* clean up and return */
       (void)inflateEnd(&strm);
       return ret == Z_STREAM_END ? Z_OK : Z_DATA_ERROR;
   }
   ```

In fact, the second snippet comes from the official zlib usage example [zpipe.c](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html), I changed only the invocation of `inflateInit(&strm);` to `inflateInit2(&strm, 16 + 15);` according to [this zlib gzip discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838699/how-can-i-decompress-a-gzip-stream-with-zlib), but now I have no idea why it fails, anyone could help?

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment, `inf()` is returning `Z_OK`, which means that the gzip stream is being successfully decompressed and verified.

What do you mean "output is only 11 bytes"?  Your `inf()` function can produce no output at all.

Comment: Sorry for reply late as the past two days are weekends, I do open the file with `binary` option, and `inf()` returns `Z_OK`, whose value is 0, I have debugged within this function, there is no any error.

Comment: Yes, I do agree with you, it should output nothing, but in fact it produced the output with 11 bytes, every byte is 0. I pasted the sample file here: http://www.filehostfree.com/?d=51F605CA1, really appreciate if you could have a test on it.

Comment: I don't have time to debug your code.  You can count the bytes generated in `inf()` and/or write them out to check that the decompression is taking place correctly.  Your 11 bytes are coming from somewhere else entirely, since your `inf()` as shown produces no output.

Comment: Sorry that my comment is not clear: the **output**, I do NOT mean it is the output of `inf()`, it does produce nothing; I mean the `out` variable defined inside `inf()`, when debugging the program, the `out` variable holds 11 bytes of zero. However, thanks for your help, I will avoid `inf*` functions and use `gz*` to solve the problem.

Comment: Your statement again makes no sense.  `out` is a pointer.  `have` indicates how much data is at `out` on each inner loop.  You need to add up the values of `have` over the loops to determine how much data was produced.  Or write out `have` bytes each time to a file and see how big the file is at the end.  See the `fwrite` in the original [zpipe.c](http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html).

Comment: I'm sorry that this program is not very logical, but I just use it to debug (this is not production code), step into the function, and trace every variable's state. I know you are warring about that the second loop may overwrite the first loop' data in `out`, but result is, both loops are only executed once, there is no change for a second loop, and the the first loop produces 11 bytes into `out`.

Comment: What is `have` after that?

Comment: `have` is 11, the result size.

Comment: You need to show the entire program being run, and the data it is fed.