# Zlib Inflate data from http packet

Tags: http, gzip, zlib

I'm trying to use zlib's inflate to decompress some data I received from an http packet.

The packet is as follows:

[image]

The packet, itself, says that it's encoded with gzip, so I think it should work. However, when I run the data through the inflate function, I get "invalid block type". To be clear, I'm only passing in the highlighted portion of the packet to the inflate function. What am I missing?

Here is the code I'm using to decompress the data:

```
int Decompress(const u_char* strStreamIn, int nStreamInLen, u_char* strStreamOut)
{
  int ret = -1;
  int err = -1;

  z_stream strm  = {0};
  strm.total_in  = strm.avail_in  = nStreamInLen;
  strm.total_out = strm.avail_out = nStreamInLen * 6;
  strm.next_in   = (Bytef*) strStreamIn;
  strm.next_out  = (Bytef*) strStreamOut;
  strm.zalloc    = Z_NULL;
  strm.zfree     = Z_NULL;
  strm.opaque    = Z_NULL;

  err = inflateInit2(&strm, -MAX_WBITS);
  if (err == Z_OK) {
    err = inflate(&strm, Z_FINISH);
    if (err == Z_STREAM_END) {
      ret = strm.total_out;
    }
    else {
      inflateEnd(&strm);
      return err;
    }
  }
  else {
    inflateEnd(&strm);
    return err;
  }
  inflateEnd(&strm);
  return ret;  
}
```

Comment: According to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872152/decompress-with-gz-functions-succeeded-but-failed-with-inflate-functions-using?rq=1) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838699/how-can-i-decompress-a-gzip-stream-with-zlib?lq=1), I should be using: `inflateInit2(&strm, 16+MAX_WBITS);` But even when I do so, I get "unknown header flags set".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to use `inflateInit2()` with the second parameter as 31 to request gzip decompression.  If you are feeding it the `1f 8b 08 00 ...`, then you won't get "unknown header flags set".  That must not be what you're doing.

By the way, it does nothing to set `total_in` and `total_out` where you do, since they are set to zero by `inflateInit[2]()`.  Setting them to the values you did in an effective location, e.g. after `inflateInit`, makes no sense either.

Setting `avail_out` to six times the input size is a guess, and won't always be sufficient.  If it's not sufficient, then you'll get an error with `Z_FINISH`.  You should be using a loop to call `inflate()` as many times as needed to process the input and produce the output.

I recommend that you read [`zlib.h`](http://zlib.net/manual.html), and then read [how to use zlib](http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html).

Comment: Mark, thanks for confirming that my code is (mostly) correct, and after taking your suggestion and looking closer at the data I'm passing in, I found the problem. There was a bug in a function that I wrote that copies one buffer to another one. I also removed the initialization of `total_in` and `total_out`. I set `avail_out` to 6 times the input just to get the function working. I'm now going to fix that to be more accurate. Thanks for all your help!