# Read in Python compressed data in C, using zlib

Tags: python, c, numpy, compression, zlib

I have a C code that writes several data files for a physics simulation. These data files are basically text files containing a 2d map of values, ranging from -1 to +1. They can be quite big (around 100 Mb each), but since many of the values are usually the same (long strings of +1 or -1), I thought that compressing them would be a good idea.

The relevant part of the C code that was **writing** the file was this:

```
FILE *fp1;
char file1[] = "output_file.dat";
fp1 = fopen(file1,"w");
for ( i = 0; i < Nx; i++ ) {
    for ( j = 0; j < Ny; j++ ) {
        fprintf(fp1, "%.5f ", creal(phi[i*Ny+j]));
    }
    fprintf(fp1, "\n");
}
fclose(fp1);
```

And the relevant part of the Python code that was **reading** the file was:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt("output_file.dat")
```

Now, I am trying to add compression using `zlib` library. I changed the C code in the following way:

```
# include <zlib.h>
gzFile fp1;
char file1[] = "output_file.dat";
fp1 = gzopen(file1,"w");
for ( i = 0; i < Nx; i++ ) {
    for ( j = 0; j < Ny; j++ ) {
        gzprintf(fp1, "%.5f ", creal(phi[i*Ny+j]));
    }
    gzprintf(fp1, "\n");
}
gzclose(fp1);
```

And the Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import zlib
compressed_data = open("output_file.dat", 'rb').read() 
data = zlib.decompress(compressed_data)
```

The C code seems to work nicely. The data files are being written and they are smaller than 2 Mb (which is reasonable, given the redundancy of the contents). Unfortunately, the Python script gives me an error:

```
error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

Anybody can point me in the right direction on how to debug this? Thank you!

Comment: You need https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution turned out to be very simple. Basically, if I write the data files using the `.gz` extension:

```
# include <zlib.h>
gzFile fp1;
char file1[] = "output_file.gz";
fp1 = gzopen(file1,"w");
for ( i = 0; i < Nx; i++ ) {
    for ( j = 0; j < Ny; j++ ) {
        gzprintf(fp1, "%.5f ", creal(phi[i*Ny+j]));
    }
    gzprintf(fp1, "\n");
}
gzclose(fp1);
```

Then, I can use `loadtext` function to read them, and they will be automatically decompressed by numpy:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt("output_file.gz")
```

Alternatively, I could still use the `zlib.decompress` function, but passing it one more argument (as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838699/how-can-i-decompress-a-gzip-stream-with-zlib) question):

```
zlib.decompress(compressed_data, 15 + 32)
```