# python equivalent of C++ z_stream inflate

Tags: python, c++, gzip, zlib

I am trying to decompress a `.gz` file that comes from a material board with custom headers using python.

I have as example a `C++` file that decompress that file using the `inflateInit2` function from the `zlib` the following way :

```
inflateInit2(&stream,MAX_WBITS + 16);
```

where `stream` is a `z_stream`. My usage of the lib in python is as follow :

```
f = open("../myfile.gz", "rb").read()
zlib.decompress(f, zlib.MAX_WBITS)
```

where I change the second parameter of the `decompress` function trying several possibilities, because the python library does not include the `inflateInit2` methode.

I've found [this topic that gives various example of usage of the lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838699/how-can-i-decompress-a-gzip-stream-with-zlib), but none of them work (or the `C++` calculus of `W_BITS`) in my case and always generate one of these error :

- `invalid block type`
- `incomplete or truncated stream`
- `inconsistent stream state`

The `C++` code seems to be deleting the generic `.gz` header to use a custom one because the compression algorithm contain this line that is then prepend to the data.

```
uint8_t headerGz[] = {0x1F, 0x8b, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
```

So my guess is that these header does not match the usual ones and that is why either `gunzip` or `libz` cannot decompress the file. Maybe also the `z_stream` way of doing treat the file in a different way.

Am I missing something ?
Many thanks !
Kev'

Answer (score 1):

```
import gzip
with gzip.open("../myfile.gz", "rb") as gz:
    gz.read()
```

Comment: Hey! This raise an `EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached`, so my guess is that the file do not comply with the `libz` standards, as I have no control on that file I have to search this way.

Comment: That code will work the same as `inflate()` with your invocation of `inflateInit2()`. So whatever issue the Python code is seeing, so would your C++ example.

Comment: You would need to provide the C++ code here so we could see what it's doing with the header. The pre-pending of eight bytes is odd, since the minimal gzip header is ten bytes.