How to deal with gzip-compressed encoded data in Delphi?
I can't seem to figgure out how to deal with gzip-compressed encoded data in Delphi.
I have created a sample application:
program GetRequestWithGzip;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.Net.HttpClient,
  System.Net.URLClient,
  System.NetConsts;

var
  Client: TNetHTTPClient;
  Response: IHTTPResponse;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
  HttpHeaders: TNetHeaders;

begin
  try
    Client := TNetHTTPClient.Create(nil);
    try
      // Set the Accept-Encoding header
      SetLength(HttpHeaders, 1);
      HttpHeaders[0].Name := 'Accept-Encoding';
      HttpHeaders[0].Value := 'gzip, deflate';

      // Prepare a stream for the response
      Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        // Perform the GET request
        Response := Client.Get('https://www.google.com', Stream, HttpHeaders);

        // Check if the response was gzip-encoded
        if Response.ContentEncoding = 'gzip' then
        begin
          Writeln('Response is gzip encoded. Please decompress to read.');
          // Here, you would add your gzip decompression logic
        end
        else
        begin
          // If the response is not encoded, simply output the response
          Stream.Position := 0; // Reset stream position to read from the beginning
          Writeln('Response received: ', Stream.Size, ' bytes');
          // Further processing of Stream as needed
        end;
      finally
        Stream.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Client.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;

  Writeln('Press Enter to exit.');
  Readln;
end.

When I deal with it like this I always get just 10 bytes stating I have a header:
unit TGZDecompression;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, System.ZLib;

function DecompressGzipStream(const Input: TStream): TBytes;

implementation

type
  TGzipHeader = packed record
    ID1, ID2, CM, FLG: Byte;
    MTIME: Cardinal;
    XFL, OS: Byte;
  end;

  TGzipFlag = (FTEXT, FHCRC, FEXTRA, FNAME, FCOMMENT);
  TGzipFlags = set of TGzipFlag;

procedure SkipGzipHeader(const Stream: TStream);
var
  Header: TGzipHeader;
  Flags: TGzipFlags;
  XLEN: Word;
  B: Byte;
begin
  Stream.Read(Header, SizeOf(Header));
  if (Header.ID1 <> $1F) or (Header.ID2 <> $8B) then
    raise Exception.Create('Not a valid gzip stream');

  Flags := TGzipFlags(Byte(Header.FLG));

  if FEXTRA in Flags then
  begin
    Stream.Read(XLEN, SizeOf(XLEN));
    Stream.Seek(XLEN, soCurrent); // Skip the extra fields
  end;

  if FNAME in Flags then
    repeat
      Stream.Read(B, 1);
    until B = 0;

  if FCOMMENT in Flags then
    repeat
      Stream.Read(B, 1);
    until B = 0;

  if FHCRC in Flags then
    Stream.Seek(2, soCurrent); // Skip the CRC16 for the header
end;

function DecompressGzipStream(const Input: TStream): TBytes;
var
  DecompressionStream: TDecompressionStream;
  MemoryStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  SkipGzipHeader(Input);
  DecompressionStream := TDecompressionStream.Create(Input, False); // Do not own the stream
  MemoryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    MemoryStream.CopyFrom(DecompressionStream, 0);
    SetLength(Result, MemoryStream.Size);
    MemoryStream.Position := 0;
    MemoryStream.Read(Result, MemoryStream.Size);
  finally
    DecompressionStream.Free;
    MemoryStream.Free;
  end;
end;

end.

The header has the following values in the watch window:
ID1=31
ID2=139
CM=8
FLG=0
TMIME=0
XFL=2
OS=255

As no flags are set the headers doesn't forward the stream past the 10 bytes.
When I call line:
MemoryStream.CopyFrom(DecompressionStream, 0);

which would decompress the data I get:

First chance exception at $00007FFFBF9753AC. Exception class EZDecompressionError with message 'data error'.

I looked at the Delphi documentation and see no data GZIP class to assist me, do I need to make one in 2024?

I use TheLazyTomcat's ZLib*.pas along with the binary zlib.dll provided by him for zlib 1.2.13 in general, but also for gzip which is just treated as a different stream type there. So far I could decode both deflate and gzip responses without problems.

Good explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22311297

I'm not overly familiar with TNetHTTPClient but since it is just a wrapper for an OS-provided HTTP client, does it not support automatically decompressing a compressed response?

Probably you could try to use 7z.dll to decompress the data. There are plenty of Delphi headers for 7z.dll out there

It looks like you're missing an argument in TDecompressionStream.Create. You want TDecompressionStream.Create(Input. -15, False) to decompress raw deflate. Or you can just leave out all of your gzip header processing and let the decompressor handle that with TDecompressionStream.Create(Input, 15+32, False). That will also automatically decompress a zlib stream, in case that is encountered instead of a gzip stream. (You're accepting deflate as well as gzip.)

Thanks to Mark Adler, I looked at the documentation but my search did not find any, must have been looking at the wrong help.
The code below shows Mark's answer for anyone who likes to copy it:
function DecompressGzipStream(const Input: TStream): TBytes;
var
  DecompressionStream: TDecompressionStream;
  MemoryStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  // SkipGzipHeader(Input);
  DecompressionStream := TDecompressionStream.Create(Input, 15 + 32, False);
  MemoryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    MemoryStream.CopyFrom(DecompressionStream, 0);
    SetLength(Result, MemoryStream.Size);
    MemoryStream.Position := 0;
    MemoryStream.Read(Result, MemoryStream.Size);
  finally
    DecompressionStream.Free;
    MemoryStream.Free;
  end;
end;

The help states:

Note: When decompressing files, adding to 32 indicates the automatic header detection of zlib or gzip formats. See the Advanced functions section of the zlib Manual for specific information.

Or via Help > Delphi Help > System Library Help > System.ZLib.TZDecompressionStream.Create:



"help text" from where? Please link to it.

@AmigoJack, I updated the answer for you the online link: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Athens/en/System.ZLib.TZDecompressionStream.Create

Oh, it's not for me alone - it's for anyone who ready your answer. If you cite texts then pay attention for links and formattings in those, as otherwise sense and references may be overseen.
